# Correctly raytracing reflective surfaces

Tags: java, raytracing, lighting

I'm having some trouble with raytracing reflections.

Here is what I am expecting to see:
[image: Expected]

But this is what I am actually seeing:
[image: Actual]

Now, my basic understanding of how to get the new direction of the 
reflection ray is like this:
[image: Reflection direction equation]

Here is my code that emulates that:

```
public Color calculateIlluminationModel(Vector normal, boolean isInShadow, Scene scene, Ray ray, Vector intersectionPoint)
{
    if (isInShadow)
    {
        return getColorInShadow(scene);
    }
    else
    {
        Vector originalDirection = ray.getDirection();

        Vector reflectionVector = originalDirection
                .subtract(normal
                        .multiply(2)
                        .multiply(originalDirection.dotProduct(normal)
                        )
                )
                .normalize();
        Ray reflectionRay = Ray.translateRayByEpsilon(new Ray(intersectionPoint, reflectionVector));
        return scene.getRayColor(reflectionRay);
    }
}
```

But the sphere never appears to correctly reflect anything. Is there something wrong with the way I am calculating the reflection rays?

*Note:* `scene.getRayColor(reflectionRay);` is the ray tracing component to determine the color that the ray hits. I believe it isn't the problem, but if you think it's necessary to show that piece, let me know.

Comment: Are you sure that normal and originalDirection are unit length?

Comment: @JasonC Yes. They are both normalized.

Comment: Are you sure the normals point outwards from the object and not inwards?

Comment: @JasonC Yes. The normals are always calculated outwards for spheres.

Comment: If you fudge isInShadow to be always false, what do you see?

Comment: @JasonC Oh. Duh. Yeah, that fixed the problem. The only places it _would_ reflect in this image would be in shadow. Thanks. If you want, you can put that in an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reflection math appears correct. The image appears filled with a lot of shadow color. Check to see what happens if you fudge isInShadow to be false, that should help narrow it down.

Also make sure your normals point the right direction and that your direction vectors are all normalized (you said they are, but if anybody else is having a similar issue, it's worth double checking).